Ubuntu 22.04 - Calling php's dns_get_record as user www-data fails because of permission issues on a specific host
I was running into issues calling PHP's getimagesize function and managed to find that no domain name can be resolved by PHP.
If I run the following command php8.2 -r "var_dump(dns_get_record('google.com'));" as my regular user on the specific server, I get the expected result.
The same command run as the www-data user (sudo -u www-data php8.2 -r "var_dump(dns_get_record('google.com'));") fails on this server but works as expected on another host.
I tried running it with strace (sudo -u www-data strace -f -yyyyyyy  php8.2 -r "var_dump(dns_get_record('google.com'));") on both servers, and I can see that there are permission issues:
openat(AT_FDCWD</home/ixm>, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD</home/ixm>, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD</home/ixm>, "/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD</home/ixm>, "/etc/resolv.conf", 0x7ffef68404c0, 0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD</home/ixm>, "/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
openat(AT_FDCWD</home/ixm>, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

Those errors are not present on the server where the call works.
I've tried to purge apache2 and reinstall it completely and I get the same result.
I've also tried to specifically give all permissions to www-data on /etc/resolv.conf by using setfacl to no avail.
Thanks for your help!

I finally managed to fix the issue, it was indeed linked to permissions but not at all what I was expecting.
root@ixm-i6:/home/ixm# sudo -u www-data namei -l /etc/hosts
f: /etc/hosts
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 /
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 etc
               hosts - Permission denied

I then inspected the permissions on /
root@ixm-i6:/home/ixm# getfacl /
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x

And removed the additional permissions
root@ixm-i6:/home/ixm# setfacl -x u:www-data / /etc

And it was working:
root@ixm-i6:/home/ixm# sudo -u www-data namei -l /etc/hosts
f: /etc/hosts
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root etc
-rwxr-xr-x root root hosts

I have no idea why removing permissions improved the situation but it is definitely what fixed the issue... If anyone has an explanation, I would be glad to hear it.
